# Minimize number of routes to cover all EDGEs in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

**Overview**
I have a directed graph with about 35'000 nodes and about 400'000 edge (a node is usually connected with multiple nodes).
some edges are unidirectional while others are bidirectional.
Some nodes can be Source and/or Sink but never both at the same time.

**Objective**
Develop an algorithm that minimizes number of routes to cover all edges of the graph also using different couples of source and sink; of course saving these routes.

**Constraints**
Nodes can't be visited more than once in a single route but they can appear in different routes.
Starting from a node connected with more than one nodes, algorithm can add to the route only one edge starting from it. Others edge cannot be used in this route

[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11919837/graph.jpg) there is a simply representation of the graph. Algorithm has to find some paths to cover all edges. It will be better find the minimum number of paths.

*I don't want use a force brute search of all possible paths because it will be too slow.
It would be nice use a different source and sink for each route so that can be crossed in parallel (if these haven't nodes in common).*

*Maybe this problem can be resolved with the [Graph Coloring Technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), but I can't realize in my mind an algorithm to adapt it.*

Comment: If you have 35k edges and 400k nodes, the some of those nodes are not connected by any edges, therefore a route connecting all the nodes cannot exist. I'm assuming that's a typo, so please fix. As for the actual problem,

Comment: You're right! I forgot to say that an edge can connect more than 2 nodes like an hypergraph. But when an edge is choosen during calculation of a route it can connect only 2 nodes (it is like having a replicated edge that can be used only once)

Comment: That makes things... interesting... The only thing that comes to my mind right now is DFS with fail-fast checks (to verify whether there are nodes that no longer can be connected. Apart from that, You could change the data representation to minimize the amount of operatins needed - I would try representing the edges as zero-value nodes (as opposed to one-value original nodes) and create an edge for every edge-node to node connection - this way you need to find a path of a total value equal to the starting number of nodes.

It's just a loose concept, but I hope it helps.

Comment: thank for your reply! but I think it isn't a feasible way.. is impossible find a path that cover all nodes because of graph infrastructure. A one node can be connected to other 20 nodes; starting from this node i can choose only one edge and others will be unreachble because i can't create cycle. Maybe is better modell the problem in a different way, by swapping nodes with edge and solution is to cover all edge..
I will write again the post